# Load and use saved Keras model.h5

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I try to a KerasClassifier (wrapper)  into `final_model.h5`

```
validator  = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = validator.fit(train_images, train_labels)
best_estimator = grid_result.best_estimator_
best_estimator.model.save("final_model.h5")
```

And then I want to reuse the model

```
from keras.models import load_model
loaded_model = load_model("final_model.h5")
```

But it seems like `loaded_model` is now a `Sequential` object instead. In other words it is different from `KerasClassifier` object like `best_estimator`

I want to reuse some method like `score` which is available in `KerasClassifier`, which is not available in `Sequential` model. What should I do?

Also, I would like to know more about how to continue the training process left off on `final_model.h5`. What can I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the end you saved the Keras model as HDF5, not the KerasClassifier that is just an adapter to use with scikit-learn.

But you don't really need the KerasClassifier instance, you want the `score` function and this in keras is called `evaluate`, so just call `model.evaluate(X, Y)` and this will return a list containing first the loss and then any metrics that your model used (most likely accuracy).

To continue training the model, just load it and call `model.fit` with the new training set and that's it.

Comment: Great. Could you please extend the answer a bit to address my second question, which asks about how to pick up the training after loading the `final_model.h5`?
Assume that I have new training data and I want to continue the training. Thank you!